# how to slow down API calls in ruby script on Amazon Product API

Tags: ruby, amazon-product-api

Ruby Script:

I am dealing with a rate limit on the order of 1 request per second.  How can I slow my script down so I don't receive errors?

Update: It was suggested I use Kernel [sleep][1]

I attempted to implement as follows: (Where Items is a table in the database)

```
  Item.limit(10000).each do |item|

  sleep(1)

  //Make API Call Here

  end
```

I think it's working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You alway can use [`Kernel#sleep`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-sleep).

Comment: I have no idea how I would implement that in my script.

Comment: @NickLashinsky if you asking code on SO you should include your attempt what you tried so far, instead it is off-topic.

Comment: You would look up the `sleep` method in the documentation and read what it says. It's an incredibly easy thing to implement, and your response shows you didn't try. You didn't take the time to provide any code showing what you wrote so we can't help you beyond that.

Comment: Problem solved. Docs are less cryptic than they looked.